# c# Plugin Loader dependency/reference question

Tags: c#, plugins

I have a simple Plugin loader project written in c# as a console app. 
The PluginLoader looks in "plugins" folder for .dll files, using my custom abstract class MyPlugin type. MyPlugin is an IDisposable, contains basic info of plugin such as Name, Author, Order. Contains abstract initialize method.

PluginLoader loads the plugins into assembly, instantiates, then initializes them in order.

I have plugin Foo and Bar. 
Bar references Foo, to access one of it's objects (string Foo). But I get FileNotFoundException in Bar, regarding Foo assembly. Problem is, Foo class is clearly loaded and initialized.

if I add

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="plugins" />
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

this into the app config the FileNotFound exception goes away. But then I get NullReferenceException on the Foo element. Using VisualStudio debugger, it is clear that the instance is not null, and all the objects are set.

PluginLoader code

```
    class Program
{
    public static List<MyPlugin> Plugins = new List<MyPlugin>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadPlugins();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void LoadPlugins()
    {
        var pluginsDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory("plugins");
        List<FileInfo> fileInfos = pluginsDirectory.GetFiles("*.dll").ToList();
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName));
                foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
                {
                    if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyPlugin)) || !type.IsPublic || type.IsAbstract)
                        continue;

                    MyPlugin pluginInstance;

                    try
                    {
                        pluginInstance = (MyPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(
                            string.Format("Could not create an instance of plugin class \"{0}\".", type.FullName), ex);
                    }
                    Plugins.Add(pluginInstance);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    string.Format("Failed to load assembly \"{0}\".", fileInfo.Name), ex);
            }
        }
        IOrderedEnumerable<MyPlugin> orderedPluginSelector =
            from x in Plugins
            orderby x.Order, x.Name
            select x;
        foreach (MyPlugin current in orderedPluginSelector)
        {
            try
            {
                current.Initialize();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Broken plugins better stop the entire server init.
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                    "Plugin \"{0}\" has thrown an exception during initialization.", current.Name), ex);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Plugin {current.Name} initialized!");
        }

    }
}
```

Foo plugin

```
public class Plugin : MyPlugin
{
    public override string Name => "Foo";
    public override string Author => "Patrikk";

    public static Plugin Instance;

    public string Foo;

    public Plugin()
    {
        Instance = this;
        Order = 0;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Foo = "Foo";
    }
}
```

Bar plugin

```
    public class Plugin : MyPlugin
{
    public override string Name => "Bar";
    public override string Author => "Patrikk";

    public static string Bar;

    public Plugin()
    {

    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Bar = "Bar";
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Plugin.Instance.Foo + Bar);
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure what I'm missing. 
Im trying to create a PluginLoader, a "core" plugin (Foo),  and other plugins (Bar) which require and depend on the core plugin.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your assembly loading problem.  So what does "But then I get NullReferenceException on the Foo element. " mean?  Also be sure you understand Load Contexts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/

Comment: Yes it seems like assembly loading problem is fixed. But I'm in doubt since I get a new error:
I get `NullReferenceException` when I try to call on `Foo.Plugin.Instance.Foo`. Using VisualStudio debugger, It tells me that Instance is not null, and Foo string object is populated.Yet I still get the exception.

Comment: Perhaps an assembly identity issue caused by loading multiple copies of your Foo assembly.  Once the plugins a are in your probing path you should be able to follow: "The best approach is to avoid conflicts by relocating the target assembly in your application path and using the Load method with the full display name. "